# Blue Screen Windows 10 nvlddmkm.sys

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card

My windows 10 machine is having blue screen issues with weird artifacts. I do not want yet to hastily jump to conclusion and buy a new graphics card. I had a good 5 years with my friend.

[image]
Do note that the artifacts only appear at the same time during the bluescreen. I can play games or do other stuff, the bluescreen does not seem to be task specific. It can happen while im playing games, browsing chrome, or even just idling at the desktop.

It happens frequently after logging in to windows. Right now i am booted into windows 10 safe mode with networking to write this thread.

So i uninstalled my graphics driver and downloaded the latest version. on the first try it weirdly said that the driver is not compatible with this version of windows which is weird because the driver date is only 10 days ago. A restart on the PC weirdly solved that issue. After installing it thought the problem persist.

Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.18363 Build 18363
Nvidia Geforce GT 780
Nvidia Driver version 441.87

Any ideas?

Comment: Your graphics card has started to fail, graphical artifacts after you have installed a display driver, is common in a case you describe.  As for the driver incompatibility message, you have provided enough information, to explain that behavior.  Edit your question and provide the required information

Comment: @Ramhound The artifacts only happens at the same time as the blue screen, what information you may still need good sir?

Comment: You could try to uninstall all Nvidia software using the [display driver uninstaller](https://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html) and then do a clean install of a new driver

Comment: @spike_66 I have noticed that guides on the internet always mention using a dedicated software to uninstall the display driver, why is that? what is the difference if i uninstall it via device manager or control panel?

Comment: Dedicated software removes All traces of the driver, windows does not.